# Synchronizing ArrayList of BlockingQueues

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization, blockingqueue

In Java, I need an object which is an `ArrayList` of 60 `LinkedBlockingQueue`s.  The `ArrayList` will `.add()` 60 `LinkedBlockingQueue`s in the beginning of the program, while still single threaded.  Then one thread will `.add()` to the `LinkedBlockingQueue`s while another thread will `.poll()`.  Is there any need to explicitly synchronize this object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, if the list isn't modified after initialization then you don't need to synchronize it.  I recommend you use an [UnmodifiableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) instead of an ArrayList - you'll get a runtime exception if anybody tries to modify the list after it's initialized, which is preferable to having a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any need to explicitly synchronize this object?

If you fork the threads *after* you finish building the `List` then you are fine.  However, I'd use an array instead of a Collection if it is truly immutable.  You can just do:

```
BlockingQueue[] blockingQueueArray =
   blockingQueueList.toArray(new BlockingQueue[blockingQueueList.size()]);
```